# htaccess rewrite url

Tags: htaccess, redirects, url-rewriting

is it possible to create a 301 redirect for the following URL string:

Original URL:
`http://www.example.com/old/old-directory/blog-post-1.html`

Desired destination URL:
`http://www.example.com/new/new-directory/1.html`

Answer (score 1):

Using a mod_alias `Redirect` in your root `.htaccess` file:

```
Redirect 301 /old/old-directory/blog-post-1.html /new/new-directory/1.html
```

Reference:
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect